# How can I prevent the focus on the toggle button for a Bootstrap modal after the modal closes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, tooltip

I have a button that toggles a Bootstrap modal. The button itself is wrapped in a div so a tooltip shows up on hover.

When I close the modal, the button gets focused and the tooltip shows without hovering the element.

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="Tooltip">
    <button  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Toggle</button>
</span>

 <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
             </div>
             
             <div class="modal-body">
                 <p>lorem ispum dolor sit amet</p>
             </div>
             
             
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

See here exactly what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/6t3kxhLb/

The only workaround I could come up with up until now was to blur the button when the hidden.bs.modal event fires up. But I'm not really happy with the result.

#### This is my workaround:

```
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="modal"]').blur();
    });
 });
```

Do you guys know any way to prevent the focus on the toggle button when the modal closes?

Comment: Note that the Modal does this focusing for good accessibility reasons. Otherwise, the user loses what part of the page they were on after the modal closes, which is disorienting and annoying (they gotta tab/navigate all the way back to where they were).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options), you need to specify what triggers the tooltip. The options are `click`, `hover`, `focus` and `manual` while the default is to have both `hover` and `focus`. so just add `data-trigger="hover"` to your element:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="Tooltip" data-trigger="hover">
    <button  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Toggle</button>
</span>
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6t3kxhLb/1/

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea on how I can prevent the focus?

Comment: @PhuNguyen You start by [asking a proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution I used, worked like a charm:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chime in after some time on this topic. I avoid using Bootstraps data- attributes and use Jquery. I achieved this by the following...

```
// Use whatever to trigger the modal, in this case a class
// Get the modal trigger
var modalTriggerObj = $("body").find(".modal-trigger");

modalTriggerObj.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Opens the modal
  $("#modal").modal();
  // Light up the modal trigger with css
  $(this).addClass('modal-on');

  // When the modal hides ...
  $("#modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    // Return the trigger to its default state
    modalTriggerObj.removeClass('modal-on');
  });
});
```